# Is it possible for a telegram bot that is an “admin” of a channel to make a user of a channel an admin?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, node-telegram-bot-api

I have a telegram bot that asks a channel user a certain set of questions. Based on these answers, I would like that user to automatically become the admin of the telegram channel. Is that possible?

[image: I would like to enable my bot to make other users admins for only one privilege - to add new subscribers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

Bots can promote users using the method `promoteChatMember`. You can also select which privilege the user should have.

> Use this method to promote or demote a user in a supergroup or a
>   channel. The bot must be an administrator in the chat for this to work
>   and must have the appropriate admin rights. Pass False for all boolean
>   parameters to demote a user. Returns True on success.

Check the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#promotechatmember) to find all the details for its usage.

Comment: Just a clarification - if the owner promotes another user to “admin” with ONLY add subscriber rights, does the new admin see who the other admins are? Can he DM other admins?